# Freedom in the choice of U in the decomposition $Z=UMU^\text{t}$, with Z skew-symmetric

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

### The premise

It is known [(doi:10.4153/CJM-1961-059-8)](https://dx.doi.org/10.4153%2FCJM-1961-059-8) that given any *skew-symmetric* complex matrix $Z \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ of rank $2k$, there is a unitary matrix $U$ such that
$$
Z=UMU^\text{t},
$$
with
$$
M=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \lambda_1\\ -\lambda_1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\oplus
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \lambda_2\\ -\lambda_2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\oplus \dotsb\oplus
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \lambda_k\\ -\lambda_k & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\oplus 0_{n-2k},
$$
where the $\lambda_a$ are the positive square roots of the eigenvalues of $Z^*Z$ and $0_{N}$ is the $N\times N$ zero matrix.

### The question

What is our freedom in the choice of $U$? In other words, I would like to find the subgroup of the unitary group $\Sigma\subseteq \mathrm{U}(n)$ for which we have
$$
UVMV^\text{t}U^\text{t} = UMU^\text{t},\quad \forall V\in\Sigma,
$$
that is
$$
\Sigma=\left\{ V\in\mathrm{U}(n) \,\mid\, V M V^\text{t} = M  \right\}.
$$
I know that when $\operatorname{rank}(Z)=2$
$$
\Sigma=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
u & 0 \\ 0 &v
\end{pmatrix}
\,\middle|\, u \in \mathrm{SU}(2),v\in \mathrm{U}(n-2)
\right\}
\cong  \mathrm{SU}(2) \times \mathrm{U}(n-2),
$$
and that in general
$ \mathrm{SU}(2)\times \mathrm{SU}(2)\times \dotsb \times \mathrm{SU}(2) \times\mathrm{U}(n-2k)$ (constructed in an analogous way) is a *subgroup* of $\Sigma$, but I am having trouble finding $\Sigma$ itself.